# Efficient way to create an image of millions of files for transfer

Tags: windows, transfer, windows-server-2012

I have a folder with about 45 million small zip files in subfolders, totalling about 1.5TB

I need to transfer this folder to another windows machine.

Does anybody have any good ideas on the fastest way to create a single archive or image file for transfer that I can restore on the target machine?

Comment: I decided to tar the files, and do a robocopy at the same time. Robocopy took 7 days to transfer the files, and the tar is only 20% so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really think a single 1.5TB file will be easier to copy over than the individual files? Especially considering you then have to split them up again. Also it requires twice as must disk space at both ends to hold both the archive and the small files.

I recommend using a tool with backup and resume support such as robocopy to replicate the individual files to the target machine.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx

Comment: I have to transfer the archive over the internet, and I thought the overheard of dealing with millions of files would be greater

Comment: Doing individual files is much much safer and will be quicker in the long run. If your big file gets corrupt you'll have to start again.

Comment: The OP does have a point, however. Transferring millions of files will, unless you use a specialized client that overlaps transfers, be a **lot** slower due to handshake and round trip times. If you only lose 50 milliseconds per file due to handshake and such, that's 13 hours lost for one million files.

Comment: @Damon Yes but 13 hours out of potentially hundreds if not thousands of hours of transfer time is insignificant vs getting 500 hours into the copy and having it all screw up.

Comment: Depends on your speed of course. My internet is comparatively slow, 1.5TB would take me around 11 days. On the other hand, home internet connections that are _very affordable_ and roughly 8 times faster than mine are not at all rare if you live somewhat less on the country side. Using a corporate or university internet connection, you can probably do it in under 2 hours. The speed of light (and thus the round trip times) stays the same for everybody, though. I agree with you that several smaller files (but not millions!) are better for practical reasons, though -- think aborted transfers.

Answer (score 1):

`tar -cf filename.tar path/to/small/files/*` to pack, `tar -xf filename.tar` to unpack.

`tar` is vailable for example via MinGW, or UnxUtils or [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gtar.htm). Peazip and 7z can create tar files too, but they are pretty pathetic performance-wise compared to the "genuine" tool. On my computer, the genuine `tar` utility runs 5-6 times faster on large numbers of small files (no idea why, it's just copying data from one file to another!).

Since your files are already ZIP files, it is unlikely that compression will further reduce the size. On the other hand, compression is usually in the low range of megabytes per second whereas disk read is in the hundreds. Thus, compression would *considerably* increase the time you spend creating that archive, and simply using `tar` is probably best.

Corruption should not be that much of an issue since typical transports (say, FTP) are reliable, and the underlying protocols and network layers are pretty good at checksumming and detecting bit errors.
Still, you might consider creating *several* smaller tar-files because if you only transfer one huge file and the FTP server at the other end crashes (or your internet connection gets a hiccup) after you have transferred 1.49 of your 1.5 TB, this will be *pretty annoying*. With somewhat smaller files, you don't need to resend that much.

Comment: I tried using 7zip to create an archive and it failed. I like the idea of several smaller tar files

Answer (score 0):

Use the (unix) tool rsync - there are several windows versions of it. It has the big advantage of transferring only deltas, but in one TCP connection, so it always gives you full speed, and you just restart it should there be an interrupt.

Comment: I just found Deltacopy (http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp), which uses the rsync protocol, has a windows gui, and is free unter the GPL.